# Duplicate Data in CoreData how to eradicate with unique ID from JSON Parsing

Tags: ios, iphone

I am parsing data JSON and storing to the Coredata but every time i launch the application it is again storing the data how to stop this i know using nspredicate and with unique id i can do this but progromatically how to write code

Comment: Take a look at RestKit, or simply don't reload the same data multiple times. Have you tried any predicate based solution?

Comment: no i did not try predicate i tried restkit but i felt so hard with the cocoapods so i stopped using restkit

Comment: i want some sample how to check the id is existing or not help me with that

Comment: What do you mean ` i felt so hard with the cocoa pods ` ?

Comment: every time i run the project #import<RestKit/CoreData> not found i tried a lot can you help me with that

Comment: i actually very intrested to use RestKit but every time i start working with that i get many errors

Comment: So you used cocoa pods and followed the install instructions from github? Use version 0.24.1 not 0.20.0. And you opened the workspace?

Comment: okay but how to parse the json data with the RestKit and Put in to the coredata

Comment: yaa i opened and i will try again

Comment: You need to have browsed the docs and tried something, if you have an issue then ask a question with the code and describe the errors seen. You're being far too general and broad currently